# MS access after macro cannot insert newly created record in Linked table

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables in MS access. An access local table and mysql linked table.
Both tables have same fields. I have set up after insert macro on access local table to sync linked table through a VBA script.

But the newly created record is not inserted into linked table.
It refresh previous records but new record in not inserted into linked table.
Please find my VBA function which is called using setlocalvar event afterinsert macro .
Is there any way to sync linked table with local table in access ?
Thanks

```
Public Function Synccategory() As String
  SQLQUERY = "Insert Into tblcategories1 select * from tblcategories where `Category ID` not in (select `Category ID` from tblcategories1) "
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL SQLQUERY
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't enclose object names in apostrophes, use brackets [ ].

```
SQLQUERY = "Insert Into tblcategories1 select * from tblcategories where [Category ID] not in (select [Category ID] from tblcategories1) "
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLQUERY
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply but my original question is that I cannot get newly created record from the query mentioned above. This query runs just "after insert" event,

Comment: @AwaisSheikh: Show more code! You create records in`tblcategories1`before and can't access them in select part of insert query?

Comment: Well, your query syntax should have failed regardless. If saving record is issue then edit question to show code related to saving record. I don't use macros, not even Data Macros. If you are going to use any VBA, why bother with macros?

Comment: @June7: OP wants to sync mysql-tables to access-tables on access-table level (data-macros). But of course his sql fails, but he doesn't notice, because of`SetWarings False`(Ignorance is bliss;)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Let's hope OP does now.